# Binarize a string to filter documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am connecting to a mongo database having one collection in it. The documents look like the following :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('8590k0916546317edb532612'),
  key_id: Binary.createFromBase64('ABC/0DEGSEWzZXJhGHTyFw==', 3),
  status: 7,
  modified_at: ISODate('2018-10-21T16:23:49.506Z')
}
```

I would like to find all documents that have a specific value of `key_id`. The problem is that the specific value I am filtering on is a string UUID, say `d22d4619-3f40-46ab-bc7b-26f293258d7a`, and when I just do :

```
db.collection.find({ key_id: "d22d4619-3f40-46ab-bc7b-26f293258d7a" })
```

It doesn't find anything.

How can I make the uuid in the binary format expected in the key_id field?

**EDIT**

I found in python a way to encode/decode back thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515237/decoding-base64-guid-in-python) thread:

```
u = uuid.UUID("d22d4619-3f40-46ab-bc7b-26f293258d7a")
base64.b64encode(u.bytes) # b'0i1GGT9ARqu8eybykyWNeg=='
```

Then I use the string byte that Python returns in the mongo shell :

```
db.collection.find({ key_id: Binary.createFromBase64('0i1GGT9ARqu8eybykyWNeg=='})
```

**Is there a way to do this decoding step directly in the mongo query ?**